# How to create a round area to to fix image as Facebook avatar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm creating an input, where users can upload file images to change avatars as Facebook does. But I know Facebook creates a cycle area and users can fix the image to fit with that circle (image below). I have no idea how to do it. Tell me if you know
[image]

Comment: use this library https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/
example https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/examples/crop-a-round-image.html

Comment: Are you saying you want the user to be able to first select and image and then move it within a circle until it's at the place they want it?

Comment: yeah, but I got the answer that is using react-avatar-editor npm

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest way to achieve such an effect is to overlay a rounded rectangle with a transparent black outline over the image. However, you will also need to wrap the element in another container with `overflow` set to `hidden` to limit the backdrop to the image.

Here is a quick demo:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;

  border-radius: 100%;
  outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100vmax solid;

  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;

  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300">
</div>
```